# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I have defiend the following model class inside my asp.net mvc wen application:-

```
public class CustomerDetails
{
    public AccountDefinition AccountDefinition {get; set;}
    public SDOrganization SDOrganization {get; set;}
    public ICollection<SiteDefinition> SiteDefinition { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AaaPostalAddress> AaaPostalAddress { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AaaContactInfo> AaaContactInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserSiteMapping> UserSiteMapping { get; set; } 
}
```

Then i write the following query:-

```
var customerDetails = entities.AccountDefinitions
    .Where(a => a.ORG_ID == id)
    .Select(cd => new CustomerDetails
    {
        AccountDefinition = cd,
        SDOrganization = cd.SDOrganization,
        AaaPostalAddress = cd.SDOrganization.AaaPostalAddresses,
        AaaContactInfo = cd.SDOrganization.AaaContactInfoes,
        SiteDefinition = cd.SiteDefinitions,
        UserSiteMapping = cd.SiteDefinitions.Select(p2 => p2.UserSiteMappings) //this is raising the exception
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();

return customerDetails;
```

But i got the following misleading error :-

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I do not know exactly what is causing the error, as i am selecting the `UserSiteMapping` related to a SiteDefinition , and i am assigning these to a collection of UserSiteMapping (as defined inside my view model)????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` instead:

```
UserSiteMapping = cd.SiteDefinitions.SelectMany(p2 => p2.UserSiteMappings)
```

You may also need `ToList()` or `ToArray()` call to switch from `IEnumerable<T>` to `ICollection<T>`:

```
UserSiteMapping = cd.SiteDefinitions.SelectMany(p2 => p2.UserSiteMappings).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. but why  might the SelectMany  solve this problem ? , as in both cases (using Select or SelectMany) it should return all the UserSiteMapping objects that this related to a specific SiteDefinition ??

Comment: i tried SelectMany and Tolist. but this did not solve the problem. i will get a more misleading Error. "The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."